# RichTextBox does not display all my text.

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In my Windows Phone Application I am using [richtextbox](/questions/tagged/richtextbox)

```
    <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto"  >
            <RichTextBox x:Name="Browser" Foreground="Black" Height="Auto" cxi:WebBrowserHelper.Html="{Binding BrowserHtml}" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="460" Margin="0,0,0,0" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But not all text displays. How can I resolve this issue?

[image]
[image]

**Update1**

After I put height=700:(see second image)

**Update2**

```
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="480" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="1000" >
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto"  >
                <RichTextBox x:Name="Browser" Foreground="Black" Height="1000" cxi:WebBrowserHelper.Html="{Binding BrowserHtml}" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Width="460" Margin="0,0,0,0" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the text you are trying to display?

Comment: it scrolls only a bit, but a huge part of content was cut

Comment: How much text are you trying to display? I had a quick look, but couldn't find if there was a character limit (1024, 2048, whatever). You could try breaking the text up into runs and adding those. Though it could also be that you've not restricted the height of your scroll viewer.

Comment: Did your first example also have an outer StackPanel (just not shown)? The outer StackPanel was the cause of the ScrollViewer not working in update 2 (see answer below).

Comment: +1 for providing XAML & screenshots :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the RichTextBox, it is caused by your use of StackPanels. *Examples below reproduce the problem/solution with simple rectangles.*

A vertically oriented StackPanel expands to the size of the content. That means a ScrollViewer inside it cannot stretch correctly to fit. For a ScrollViewer to work it must be a fixed size.

### This simple example does not work for the same reason:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="480" Orientation="Vertical">
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto"  >
                       <Rectangle Fill="Aqua" Height="200"/>
                       <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="200"/>
                       <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Height="200"/>
                       <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="200"/>
                       <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="200"/>
                  </StackPanel>
             </ScrollViewer>
         </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

### This Works (no stackpanel outside ScrollViewer):

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
             <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto"  >
                  <Rectangle Fill="Aqua" Height="200"/>
                  <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="200"/>
                  <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Height="200"/>
                  <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="200"/>
                  <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="200"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Update 2 has a ScrollViewer with height=1000... you need to specify a much smaller height for it to scroll... your ScrollViewer extends offscreen.

Comment: it scrolling, but not enough, the problem is in something else because when I change 1000-> 700 it doesn't help

Comment: Sorted by removing StackPanel and changing ScrollViewer to stretch to fit the content grid. If you had tried less than 700 (say 400) you would have seen a different result. 700 was too close to full screen height to show the problem. *(removed my earlier comments as noise)*

Answer (score 1):

You must set height="auto" in RichTextBox. The following code works for me:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Name="richTextBox" Style="{StaticResource RichTextBoxStyle1}" Height="auto"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

when using ScrollViewer u must specify the height element of it (fixed or dynamic as in grid). otherwise it takes all the height as per the content, even if it goes beyond the screen.
so try something like this 'ScrollViewer Height="700"....'

Comment: remember, height of scrollViewer not its child.